# knockout sammy.js navigation issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, sammy.js

I have a scenario like this.

1. Initially loaded when page is navigated to #Action.
2. Once the select action is performed data-bind="with tag is loaded"
3. User click on "Do Something" action is performed. Which replaces the whole "parentNode"
4. Now When the user clicks back, and the sammy.js notices the hash tag #Action/:id, I need to load the #Action to get back the main View and then select the id to load the data-bind="with" tag again.

How can I do this?

Currently the page does go back to "Action/:id" but since main view is not loaded it doesn't do anything. I have used "this.redirect("#Action") then selected the node, but the doesn't work.

```
<div id="parentNode">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: items">
       <li data-bind="click: $root.selectItem">
          <h2><span data-bind="text: Sometext"></span></h2>
       </li>
    </ul>
    <div data-bind="with: selectedItem">
       <a data-bind="click: loadSomething">Do Something</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my viewmodel i have this:

```
viewModel.selectItem= function (item) {
    location.hash = "Action/" + item.id();
}

viewModel.loadSomething = function () {
    location.hash = "Action/" + viewModel.someSelectedItem().id() +"/SubAction";
}

$.sammy(function () {

  this.get('#Action', function () {
     $.ajax({
         url: '@Url.Action("GetMainView")',
         type: "GET",
         data: self.someId(),
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (result) {
           $("#parentNode").html(result.message);
         }
   });

  this.get('#Action/:id', function () {
      var id = this.params["id"];
      var matchItem = ko.utils.arrayFirst(viewModel.MainItems(), function (item) {
                return item.id() == id;
       });

       viewModel.someSelectedItem(matchItem);
  });

  this.get('#Action/:id/SubAction', function () {
    var id = this.params['id'];
    $.ajax({
         url: '@Url.Action("ViewSomething")',
         type: "GET",
         data: { id: id },
         success: function (result) {
             $('#parentNode').html(result.message);
         }
    });
 });
});
```

Sample Code: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=33048714B5BF3B4B!913

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Select "SubItems" under any of the items listed (Item 1, Item 2, Item 3)
2. Select any of the Sub Items that Label (Sub Item 1, Sub Item 2)
3. Partial View will be shown with "Sub Item {x}" with "Next View" link
4. Click "Next View" link.
5. "Next Partial View" will be shown.
6. Press the back button.

The thing I am trying to do is to load the SubItems and Select "Sub Item 1" view.

1. List item

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will work, but could you create a separate helper function to load the main view. Then it would be the case of the following:

```
this.get('#Action', function () {
    LoadMainView();
}

this.get('#Action/:id', function () {
    if($('#parentNode').length == 0) {
        LoadMainView(function() {
             var id = this.params["id"];
             var matchItem = ko.utils.arrayFirst(viewModel.MainItems(), function (item) {
                 return item.id() == id;
             });

             viewModel.someSelectedItem(matchItem);
        })
    }
}
```

Your LoadMainView function would then accept a callback and be something like this:

```
function LoadMainView(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetMainView")',
        type: "GET",
        data: self.someId(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#parentNode").html(result.message);
            if(typeof callback == "function") {
                callback();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I haven't been able to test this in your solution (I get an error opening it), but I believe that's the general structure to do what you are asking.