# How to refresh div with data-bind="with" tag

Tags: knockout.js, sammy.js

I have a collection of items, and I simply want to refersh the item that has already been selected!

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li><a data-bind="click: $root.select"><span data-bind="text: name"></span></a></li>
</ul>
<div data-bind="with: selectedItem">
    <h1 data-bind="text: name"></h1>
</div>

self.items = ko.observableArray([
            { name: "Bungle", type: "Bear" },
            { name: "George", type: "Hippo" },
            { name: "Zippy", type: "Unknown" }
        ]);

        self.select = function (item) {

            location.hash = "Action/" + item.name;
        }

        self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
```

For my applicant I just need to do something that will tell div that has the selectedItem to refresh itself.

I have tried valueHasMutated(); but doesn't work.

---

Sample Code: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=33048714B5BF3B4B!913

### Steps to Reproduce:

1. Select "SubItems" under any of the items listed (Item 1, Item 2, Item 3)
2. Select any of the Sub Items that Label (Sub Item 1, Sub Item 2)
3. Partial View will be shown with "Sub Item {x}" with "Next View" link
4. Click "Next View" link.
5. "Next Partial View" will be shown.
6. Press the back button.

The think I am trying to do is to load the SubItems and Select "Sub Item 1" view.

Comment: Have you initialized your viewModel

Comment: yeah it binds and everything. Its related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765127/knockout-sammy-js-navigation-issue. i got everything to work. event he selected item is not null and still doesn't load the UI. If i click another item then it starts working.

Comment: change the 'select' function to this: self.select = function(item){ localtion.hash = "Action/" + item.name; self.selectedItem(item); };